# Scraping product classifcation when HTML has no proper hierarchy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the classification for products (category, subcategory, subsubcategory) and compare between websites. For other websites, the HMTL allowed quick identification of the hierarchy. However, this particular one is using what seems to be internal values (class= cat_[*a number that means something to them*]).

With this, I get the text but without a way to properly extract the hierarchy:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for i in soup.find_all("li", class_="cat_858"):
        print(i.text)
```

Seasonal is the category, Gardening - Landscaping and Garden Tools are subcategories, and all the rest are subsubcategories. However, I cannot figure out a way to extract that from the html to export in csv. Among other things, the whole block is treated as 1 thing since they all share the main "li" tag, only differentiated by the class cat number which is not "logical" enough to use.

What I want is to be able to output that:

> ```
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Soil - Potting Mix
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Fertilizer: Trees - Flowers - Garden
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Fertilizer: Lawn
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Manure - Compost
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Bulbs - Seeds
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Insecticides - Pesticides
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Weed Killers - Pest Control
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Purchasing Restriction Pesticides
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Landscape Fabric - Ground Covers - Mulch
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Blocks - Borders - Concrete Slabs
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Asphalt Repair & Sealants
> SEASONAL  Gardening - Landscaping Concrete Protectors & Sealants
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Shovels - Rakes
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Lawn Shears - Pruners - hedge Trimmers
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Small Tools & Accessories
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Trimmers - Lawn Mowers
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Blowers - Mulchers
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Wheelbarrows & Accessories
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Spreaders
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Sprayers
> SEASONAL  Garden Tools    Outdoor Storage
> ```

The other annoying thing is that is seems that I manually have to make a list of the category value (858 for the seasonal one) for all the main categories in the page and loop through it...

for ex: html =

```
"""<nav class="nav-menu-cat-web"><ul class='menu-cat-web clearfix' style='display:none;'>
<li class="cat_858"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/popular-seasonal.aspx">Seasonal</a>
<div class="subMenu"><ul>
<li class="cat_863 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/c863/seasonal.aspx">Gardening - Landscaping</a>
<div class="subSubMenu"><ul>
<li class="cat_908"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/soil-potting-mix/c863c908/seasonal.aspx">Soil - Potting Mix</a></li>
<li class="cat_903"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/fertilizer-trees-flowers-garden/c863c903/seasonal.aspx">Fertilizer: Trees - Flowers - Garden</a></li>
<li class="cat_904"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/fertilizer-lawn/c863c904/seasonal.aspx">Fertilizer: Lawn</a></li>
<li class="cat_905"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/manure-compost/c863c905/seasonal.aspx">Manure - Compost</a></li>
<li class="cat_898"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/bulbs-seeds/c863c898/seasonal.aspx">Bulbs - Seeds</a></li>
<li class="cat_907"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/insecticides-pesticides/c863c907/seasonal.aspx">Insecticides - Pesticides</a></li>
<li class="cat_906"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/weed-killers-pest-control/c863c906/seasonal.aspx">Weed Killers - Pest Control</a></li>
<li class="cat_1597"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/purchasing-restriction-pesticides/c863c1597/seasonal.aspx">Purchasing Restriction Pesticides</a></li>
<li class="cat_900"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/landscape-fabric-ground-covers-mulch/c863c900/seasonal.aspx">Landscape Fabric - Ground Covers - Mulch</a></li>
<li class="cat_901"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/blocks-borders-concrete-slabs/c863c901/seasonal.aspx">Blocks - Borders - Concrete Slabs</a></li>
<li class="cat_909"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/asphalt-repair-sealants/c863c909/seasonal.aspx">Asphalt Repair & Sealants</a></li>
<li class="cat_1596"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/gardening-landscaping/concrete-protectors-sealants/c863c1596/seasonal.aspx">Concrete Protectors & Sealants</a></li>
</ul></div>

</li>
<li class="cat_865 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/c865/seasonal.aspx">Garden Tools</a>
<div class="subSubMenu"><ul>
<li class="cat_918"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/shovels-rakes/c865c918/seasonal.aspx">Shovels - Rakes</a></li>
<li class="cat_914"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/lawn-shears-pruners-hedge-trimmers/c865c914/seasonal.aspx">Lawn Shears - Pruners - hedge Trimmers</a></li>
<li class="cat_917"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/small-tools-accessories/c865c917/seasonal.aspx">Small Tools & Accessories</a></li>
<li class="cat_915"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/trimmers-lawn-mowers/c865c915/seasonal.aspx">Trimmers - Lawn Mowers</a></li>
<li class="cat_921"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/blowers-mulchers/c865c921/seasonal.aspx">Blowers - Mulchers</a></li>
<li class="cat_913"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/wheelbarrows-accessories/c865c913/seasonal.aspx">Wheelbarrows & Accessories</a></li>
<li class="cat_916"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/spreaders/c865c916/seasonal.aspx">Spreaders</a></li>
<li class="cat_919"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/sprayers/c865c919/seasonal.aspx">Sprayers</a></li>
<li class="cat_920"><a href="http://www.canac.ca/en/garden-tools/outdoor-storage/c865c920/seasonal.aspx">Outdoor Storage</a></li>
</ul></div>"""
```

Many thanks !

Comment: What help you actually need ?

Comment: Sorry maybe that was unclear. I'll edit :)

Comment: When I go to the 'Seasonal' page (http://www.canac.ca/en/popular-seasonal.aspx) I see, for instance, 'Weed Killers - Pest Control', listed under 'Gardening - Landscaping'. Are you trying to get a complete, hierarchically arranged list of items at the level of 'Weed Killers'?

Comment: You may not know: to reply to someone on SO, type the at symbol to get a menu of respondents to choose from, and pick one. Otherwise, the individual to whom you're responding won't know that you have done so.

Comment: @BillBell Thanks, i've edited to show what it should come out as

Comment: The URL seems to contain all of the hierarchical data: 
`http://.../en/{subcategory}/{subsubcategory}/{some garbage}/{category}.aspx`. Maybe you could use that?

Answer (score 0):

I won't say I found this easy to make. First, locate (`first`) the top of the outline, that is, the item that contains 'Seasonal'. Now find the `ul` element that contains this, and all of the items of interest. Then find the main menu items and use them as the main navigation points.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse('http://www.canac.ca/en/home.aspx', parser)
first = tree.xpath('.//li[@class="cat_858"]/a[@href="http://www.canac.ca/en/popular-seasonal.aspx"]')[0]
containing_ul = first.xpath('../..')[0]
menuEntries = containing_ul.xpath('li/a')
menuEntryTexts = containing_ul.xpath('li/a/text()')

for menuEntry, menuEntryText in zip(menuEntries, menuEntryTexts):
    print (menuEntryText)
    subHeadings = menuEntry.xpath('../div[@class="subMenu"]/ul/li/a/text()')
    for subHeading in subHeadings:
        print ('\t', subHeading)
        link = containing_ul.xpath('//a[text()="%s"]' % subHeading)[0]
        for item in link.xpath('../div[@class="subSubMenu"]/ul/li/a/text()'):
            print ('\t\t', item)
```

The initial part of the results are these:

```
Seasonal
     Gardening - Landscaping
         Soil - Potting Mix
         Fertilizer: Trees - Flowers - Garden
         Fertilizer: Lawn
         Manure - Compost
         Bulbs - Seeds
         Insecticides - Pesticides
         Weed Killers - Pest Control
         Purchasing Restriction Pesticides
         Landscape Fabric - Ground Covers - Mulch
         Blocks - Borders - Concrete Slabs
         Asphalt Repair & Sealants
         Concrete Protectors & Sealants
     Garden Tools
         Shovels - Rakes
         Lawn Shears - Pruners - hedge Trimmers
         Small Tools & Accessories
         Trimmers - Lawn Mowers
         Blowers - Mulchers
         Wheelbarrows & Accessories
         Spreaders
         Sprayers
         Outdoor Storage
     BBQs - Stoves - Fireplaces
         BBQs - Portable Stoves
         BBQs Utensils & Accessories
         Patio Heaters
         Outdoor Fireplaces
         Logs - Wood Pellets
         Fireplace Tools & Accessories
         Wood Stoves - Black Stovepipes
         Propane - Butane
     Outdoor Furnishings
         Furniture - Patio Sets
         Swings - Benches
         Sun Shelters - Umbrellas
         Arches - Arbours
     Yard Decor
```

Comment: Thanks Bill ! Looks like I'll have some reading to do to discover etree :)